# In QT, is there a dynamic array for double, float, int... ect .. ie QDoubleArray?

Tags: c++, qt

In QT is there a dynmaic storage for values?

ie:

```
QDoubleArray x;
x.append(4.6);
x.append(4.8);
x.append(5.2);

//x.count() = 3
```

Comment: QVector? QList? Can you be more specific, what do you need to do with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
QVector<double> x;
x.push_back(4.6);
x.push_back(4.8);
x.push_back(5.2);
x.size() is 3
```

Answer (score 5):

In QT, [QStringList](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstringlist.html) is a special case, it is the only type that can be seen as a specialization of a generic container like `QList<QString>`. It mainly exists because handling lists of strings is a common problem in development, and so it provides some useful methods that a QList does not.

The QT documentation generally recommends the use of the [QList](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qlist.html) class:

```
QList<double> x;
x.push_back(4.6);
x.push_back(4.8);
x.push_back(5.2);
```

The documentation says this:

> For most purposes, QList is the right class to use. Its index-based
>   API is more convenient than QLinkedList's iterator-based API, and it
>   is usually faster than QVector because of the way it stores its items
>   in memory. It also expands to less code in your executable.
>
> If you need a real linked list, with guarantees of constant time
>   insertions in the middle of the list and iterators to items rather
>   than indexes, use QLinkedList.
>
> If you want the items to occupy
>   adjacent memory positions, use QVector.